# Finding almost similar name file using python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find two similar file names in a folder. For example-the folder can contain red_apple and red_apple or green_mango and green mangoes.But it might happen that that folder only contain one file like green mango or red_apples. How Can I check if my folder contain such similar file ?

Comment: Here is a regex which would find the examples you've presented: [`^(red|green)[_ ](apples?|mango(?:es)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/OgyX84/1)

Comment: Have a look: https://www.python-course.eu/levenshtein_distance.php

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1):

The term that you are looking for is Fuzzy Matching. There a couple of good libraries which help you with this. One of them is [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)

An ideal way would be to have a list of potential matches and then using any of the fuzzy libraries to find the closest match. Usually, these libraries give you a ratio of how close the entered word is to any of the words in the list.

You could checkout the FuzzyWuzzy example either on it's Github repo or [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fuzzywuzzy-python-library/)